# How can I make Microsoft Word do exactly what I tell it to do?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

MS Word has a lot of features that improve the experience of typical users, but annoy power users. I am a slow and deliberate user and would like to disable many of these features, as they make the results of my inputs unpredictable.

Features I would like to disable are:

- Automatic selection of entire words/paragraphs when highlighting
- Automatic addition of spaces/carriage returns when pasting
- Automatic toggle of caps lock when typing wORDS lIKE tHIS (which is necessary when typing units like kV, kJ, mW,...)

Features along this line that I do appreciate and would like to keep are:

- Automatic indention
- Automatic formatting of bulleted/numbered lists

Thanks for your help, and any other recommendations for improving Word's power-user-friendliness (like Shift+F1 or other features to enable/disable) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A quick Google search found me this: https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/10-word-2016-defaults-you-can-customize/  - I guess it covers most of your questions.

Comment: You're asking about settings that can be easily looked up in Word help or online support.  It isn't really clear what about that you are having a problem with or can't find.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under **File** > **Options**, and on the left pane, select **Advanced**. [[1](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/word-options-advanced-1b3d9436-bc3a-4c5d-a55f-17450e701663?NS=WINWORD&Version=16&SysLcid=1033&UiLcid=1033&AppVer=ZWD160&HelpId=95276&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)]

- Uncheck **When selecting, automatically select entire word**
- Uncheck **Use smart paragraph selection**
- Under **Cut, copy and paste** group click on **Settings** next to *Use smart cut and paste* and under **Individual options** uncheck the option for **Adjust sentence and word spacing automatically**

Under **File** > **Options**, on the left pane, select **Proofing** [[2](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/choose-autocorrect-options-for-capitalization-spelling-and-symbols-e7433b94-f3de-4532-9dc8-b29063a96e1f?NS=WINWORD&Version=16&SysLcid=1033&UiLcid=1033&AppVer=ZWD160&HelpId=632&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)]

- Click on **AutoCorrect Options...** and uncheck **Correct accidental usage of cAPS LOCK key**